# What is the "^" symbol for when declaring or defining a member?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm currently following a quick tutorial. And the XOR "^" symbol has cropped up in a place I've never seen it before. Exactly where the asterisk would be if I were declaring a pointer to an object.
 See it in the code snippet below.

```
COpenGL(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ parentForm, 
            GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight)
    {
        CreateParams^ cp = gcnew CreateParams;

        // Set the position on the form
        cp->X = 100;
        cp->Y = 100;
        cp->Height = iWidth;
        cp->Width = iHeight;
```

Afterwards the object cp is dereferenced as if it were a pointer to an object of CreateParams type.

So....what does the ^ mean? Google has not been too friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` is part of a Microsoft extension to C++, namely C++/CLI or C++/CX. Microsoft introduced it to denote garbage collected pointers, to be used in .NET or WinRT. You see the `gcnew` call - it means that is not a "normal" memory allocation, but its garbage collected memory from the runtime.

Comment: C++/CX is a whole different animal altogether.

Comment: @KerrekSB indeed it is, but it uses the same `^` notation, although the mechanisms under the hood are somewhat different.

Comment: Thanks, so a pointer to an object, created with a call to gcnew is donated by ^. Cheers guys

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean yes, but note that it's not only the creation that matters. It is in many ways not comparable to plain C pointers, since the garbage collector "tracks" the memory it points to and releases that memory if the object is no longer used.

Answer (score 3):

C++/CLI is a different language from C++. It is sort of an extension of C++. The key new feature is that of garbage-collected CLI objects. The type `T ^` denotes a *tracked pointer* to such an object, which is created with the new keyword `gcnew`. Similarly, `T %` denotes a *tracked reference*.

In fact, there's a whole new part of the type system, with a notion of "managed classes" (designated `ref class`/`ref struct`), which have both destructors *and* finalizers. In fact, I was once so confused about this that I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240297/repeated-destructor-calls-and-tracking-handles-in-c-cli) about that.

An excellent read is Herb Sutter's [design rationale for C++/CLI](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/C++CLIRationale.pdf).