# What really happens when I call new and delete in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Now that the C++/CLI is running above .Net runtime environment, which has its own memory management and garbage collection rules, what now exactly would happen, when you try to manage your memory structure on your own.

Comment: [Maybe of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240297/repeated-destructor-calls-and-tracking-handles-in-c-cli).

Comment: The new and delete operators still do what they always did.  You are probably talking about the gcnew operator.  No, you cannot explicitly manage garbage collected memory.  Do use a decent tutorial or book to learn about the intricacies of the destructor and finalizer of a managed class, you can't write good C++/CLI code without it.

Comment: Note: .NET doesn't actually have destructors, managed types have disposers and finalizers.... and different language bindings map these onto the language's own "destructor" concept in very different ways.